# Crear una variable map en BIRT

Tags: javascript

Tengo un informe creado, donde para asignar cabeceras a una tabla, me ahorraría muchas líneas de código disponer de un map, el problema viene que siempre falla al crear esta variable. He intentado incluso crearlos tal cual vienen en ejemplos de internet, por si era culpa mía, algún fallo que no estaba viendo, pero tampoco funcionan.
Tengo el siguiente mapa en estos momentos:

```
var animal = {};

animal['cat'] = { sound: 'meow', age:8 };
animal['dog'] = { sound: 'bark', age:10 };
animal['bird'] = { sound: 'tweet', age:2 };
animal['cow'] = { sound: 'moo', age:5 };
```

Incluso probando otras combinaciones, otras asignaciones en el mapa, declararlo de otra manera,etc. Siempre obtengo el mismo error:

```
A BIRT exception occurred. See next exception for more information.
Java class "java.lang.Object" has no public instance field or method named "sound". (/report/data-sets/script-data-set[@id="121"]/method[@name="fetch"]#13)
```

Buscando por internet he visto que en BIRT el comportamiento de javascript es diferente al puro. Es posible que BIRT no acepte mapas?

Comment: Lo que estás definiendo es un objeto normal de Javascript. El hecho de que se comporte como un mapa es circustancial, pero es Javascript básico. Ayudaría que añadieses más código para ver cómo usas ese objeto y qué es lo que falla

Comment: @PabloLozano ya falla en la inicialización del objeto, en la primera línea: animal['cat'] = { sound: 'meow', age:8 };

Comment: Mira bien el error: `Java class "java.lang.Object" has no...` Ese objeto animal seguramente debería estar "mapeado" con alguna clase de Java para que funcione

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/666868/

Comment: @PabloLozano encontré respuesta en el enlace. Muchas gracias!